# Using React Select to select between options that has an image as value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

I'm using Redux toolkit, Chakra UI and React Select to create a dashboard component whereby a user should be able to choose if he wants to display his company logo or company. I'm getting both values using the useSelector hook. I know this is possible coz I've seen it done before. How can I replicate it and how can I pass an image as a value?

```
import React, { useState } from "React"

import { Avatar } from "@chakra-ui/react"

import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

import { Select as Select1 } from "chakra-react-select";

const WidgetBuilder = () => {

const { organizationData } = useSelector((state) => state.organization);

const handleLogo = (e) => {
    setLogo(Array.isArray(e) ? e.map((x) => x.value) : []);
  };

  const logoOptions = [
    {
      value: (
        <div>
          <img src={organizationData?.businessLogo} height="30px" width="30px" />
        </div>
      ),
      label: "Company Logo"
    },
    
    {
      value: `${organizationData?.businessName}`,
      label: "Company name"
    },
  ];

return (
  <Select1
    useBasicStyles
    isMulti
    name="logo"
    colorScheme="blue"
    options={logoOptions}
    value={logoOptions?.filter((obj) =>
      logoOptions?.includes(obj.value)
     )} // set selected values
     onChange={handleLogo}
   />

{ logo === "Company Logo" && (
    <Avatar
     size="md"
     src={organizationData?.businessLogo}
     onChange={handleLogo}
     bg="black"
     color="white"
    />
)}

{ logo === "Company name" && (
    <Avatar
     size="md"
     name={organizationData?.businessName}
     onChange={handleLogo}
     bg="black"
     color="white"
    />
)}
)
}
```

Comment: What's the issue？Is there any error?